# Magento 2: How to add a phtml bloxk in cms page only?

Tags: magento2, layout, cms-pages

I want to add a phtml but this phtml should only visible in all cms page only ? how can I implement this using layout XML method ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a layout file named `cms_page_view.xml`. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block name="your_template" template="Your_Module::your-template.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. create `cms_page_view.xml` in your custom extension on following location with this code.

> Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\layout\cms_page_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="your_block_file_path" name="my_custom_block_cms" template="Vendor_Extension::cmstemplate.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

2. now create `cmstemplate.phtml` on following location.

> Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\templates\cmstemplate.phtml

added code according to your requirement.